# How to break the lines using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me,
Here two for loops, once the first iteration ends, need to begin new line

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        document.write(j);
    }
}​
```

Need output like this,

```
012345
012345
```

Pleas give me the solution.

Comment: Use `<br />` for a line break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        document.write(j);
    }
    document.write('<br />');
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        document.write(j);
    }
    document.write('<br/>');
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

​

```
<div id="append"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            $('#append').append(j);
        }
        $('#append').append('<br />');
    }​
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        document.write(j);
    }
    document.write('<br/>');
}
```